# How-to declare params in Parse.Cloud.define()

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parameters, declaration, parse-cloud-code

This should be an easy enough question. I'm not sure if this is a javascript or parse.com question but when I look at some examples I see variables like the `url` or `params` being declared like so:

```
Parse.Cloud.define('getData', function(request, response) {

      //HERE
      var params = request.params;

      //AND HERE
      var url = params.url;
    .....
```

So my question is where are the  `params` (in `params.url`) and `request` (in `request.params`) being declared before new instances of them are made?

Answer (score 1):

This is a parse.com question.

No need to declare `var params = request.params;`

`request.params` is automatically declared "and set/populated" by parse.com for every cloud function.

`request.params` stores the JSON values the caller passed in. For example, if I call `getData()` in javascript with something like this

```
Parse.Cloud.run('getData', {
   'nFIObjectId':'a',
   'rRFObject':2,
   'rFOId':'three3'
});
```

then in your getDate() cloud function, you can start using `request.params.nFIObjectId` and `request.params.rRFObject` and `request.params.rFOId`.  Their values are `'a'`, `2`, and `'three3'` respectively.

Similarly, if I call `getDate()` from a curl command like this

```
curl -X POST   -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: asdf23lj4lkjasldkfjasldfkjasklja"   -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: 123ou234laskjdfiuj3kjasdf"   -H "Content-Type: application/json"   -d '{  "nFIObjectId":"a", "rRFObject":2, "rFOId":"three3"  }' https://api.parse.com/1/functions/getData
```

your `getDate()` cloud function will get the same values for those 3 input parameters.

Comment: ` 'nFIObjectId':'a',
   'rRFObject':2,
   'rFOId':'three3'` What?

Comment: @fahtCAt that's the JSON format for name/value pairs. In this case, nFIObjectId is the name of the input parameter, where a is the value of that parameter.